# Problems minimizing a function with 2 constraints - Python

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize, minimization, cyipopt

I'm writing a program to minimize a function of several parameters subjected to constraints and bounds. Just in case you want to run the program, the function is given by:

```
def Fnret(mins):
    Bj, Lj, a, b = mins.reshape(4,N)
    S1 = 0; S2 = 0
    Binf = np.zeros(N); Linf = np.zeros(N);   
    for i in range(N):
        sbi=(Bi/2); sli=(Li/2)
        for j in range(i+1):
            sbi -= Bj[j]
            sli -= Lj[j]
        Binf[i]=sbi
        Linf[i]=sli
    
    for i in range(N):
        S1 += (C*(1-np.sin(a[i]))+T*np.sin(a[i])) * ((2*Bj[i]*Binf[i]+Bj[i]**2)/(np.tan(b[i])*np.cos(a[i]))) +\
            (C*(1-np.sin(b[i]))+T*np.sin(b[i])) * ((2*Bj[i]*Linf[i]+Lj[i]*Bj[i])/(np.sin(b[i])))
    S2 += (gamma*Bj[0]/(6*np.tan(b[0])))*((Bi/2)*(Li/2) + 4*(Binf[0]+Bj[0])*(Linf[0]+Lj[0]) + Binf[0]*Linf[0])
    j=1
    while j<(N):
        S2 += (gamma*Bj[j]/(6*np.tan(b[j])))*(Binf[j-1]*Linf[j-1] + 4*(Binf[j]+Bj[j])*(Linf[j]+Lj[j]) + Binf[j]*Linf[j])
        j += 1
    F = 2*(S1+S2)
    return F
```

where `Bj`,`Lj`,`a`, and `b` are the minimization results given by N-sized arrays with `N` being an input of the program, I double-checked the function and it is working correctly. My constraints are given by:

```
def Brhs(mins):  # Constraint over Bj
    return np.sum(mins.reshape(4,N)[0]) - Bi

def Lrhs(mins): # Constraint over Lj
    return np.sum(mins.reshape(4,N)[1]) - Li

cons = [{'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda Bj: 1.0*Brhs(Bj)},
         {'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda Lj: 1.0*Lrhs(Lj)}]
```

In such a way that the sum of all components of `Bj` must be equal to `Bi` (same thing with `Lj`). The bounds of the variables are given by:

```
bounds = [(0,None)]*2*N + [(0,np.pi/2)]*2*N
```

For the problem to be reproducible, it's important to use the following inputs:

```
# Inputs:
gamma = 17.     
C = 85.        
T = C         
Li = 1.        
Bi = 0.5           
N = 3
```

For the minimization, I'm using the cyipopt library (that is just similar to the scipy.optimize). Then, the minimization is given by:

```
from cyipopt import minimize_ipopt
x0 = np.ones(4*N) # Initial guess 
res = minimize_ipopt(Fnret, x0, constraints=cons, bounds=bounds)
```

The problem is that the result is not obeying the conditions I imposed on the constraints (i.e. the sum of Bj or Lj values is different than Bi or Li on the results). But, for instance, if I only write one of the two constraints (over Lj or Bj) it works fine for that variable. Maybe I'm missing something when using 2 constraints and I can't find the error, it seems that it doesn't work with both constraints together. Any help would be truly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

P.S.: In addition, I would like that the function result `F` to be positive as well. How can I impose this condition? Thanks!

Comment: This isn't a minimal **reproducible** example. What are `Bi` and `Li`? Global variables? Both are used within the constraint functions. Note also that your lambdas don't make sense, e.g. what's the suppose of `lambda Bj: 1.0*Brhs(Bj)`? This is just the same as  `Brhs`.

Comment: `Bi` and `Li` are inputs. Say `1`, for instance. I'm sorry if its confusing, that's how I learned to construct my constraints, the `*1.0` is not useful indeed, its just there because was `-1.0` once. One given by `Brhs` and another by `Lrhs`.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example, i.e. provide **all** your inputs (`N`, `T`, `gamma`, `Bi`, `Li`, ...) such that one can copy-paste your code snippet and reproduce your observed behaviour. Otherwise, it's nearly impossible to help properly.

Comment: Thank you @joni, I just edited the question with the program inputs so it can be reproducible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, based on @joni suggestions, I could find a stationary point respecting the constraints by adopting the `trust-constr` method of `scipy.optimize.minimize` library. My code is running as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize

# Inputs:
gamma = 17      
C = 85.        
T = C         
Li = 2.         
Bi = 1.           
N = 3          # for instance

# Constraints:
def Brhs(mins):  
    return np.sum(mins.reshape(4,N)[0]) - Bi/2
def Lrhs(mins):
    return np.sum(mins.reshape(4,N)[1]) - Li/2

# Function to minimize:
def Fnret(mins):
    Bj, Lj, a, b = mins.reshape(4,N)
    S1 = 0; S2 = 0
    Binf = np.zeros(N); Linf = np.zeros(N);   
    for i in range(N):
        sbi=(Bi/2); sli=(Li/2)
        for j in range(i+1):
            sbi -= Bj[j]
            sli -= Lj[j]
        Binf[i]=sbi
        Linf[i]=sli
    
    for i in range(N):
        S1 += (C*(1-np.sin(a[i]))+T*np.sin(a[i])) * ((2*Bj[i]*Binf[i]+Bj[i]**2)/(np.tan(b[i])*np.cos(a[i]))) +\
            (C*(1-np.sin(b[i]))+T*np.sin(b[i])) * ((2*Bj[i]*Linf[i]+Lj[i]*Bj[i])/(np.sin(b[i])))
    S2 += (gamma*Bj[0]/(6*np.tan(b[0])))*((Bi/2)*(Li/2) + 4*(Binf[0]+Bj[0])*(Linf[0]+Lj[0]) + Binf[0]*Linf[0])
    j=1
    while j<(N):
        S2 += (gamma*Bj[j]/(6*np.tan(b[j])))*(Binf[j-1]*Linf[j-1] + 4*(Binf[j]+Bj[j])*(Linf[j]+Lj[j]) + Binf[j]*Linf[j])
        j += 1
    F = 2*(S1+S2)
    return F

eps = 1e-3
bounds = [(0,None)]*2*N + [(0+eps,np.pi/2-eps)]*2*N       # Bounds

cons = ({'type': 'ineq', 'fun': Fnret},
        {'type': 'eq', 'fun':  Lrhs},
        {'type': 'eq', 'fun':  Brhs})

x0 = np.ones(4*N) # Initial guess
res = minimize(Fnret, x0, method='trust-constr', bounds = bounds, constraints=cons, tol=1e-6)

F = res.fun
Bj = (res.x).reshape(4,N)[0]
Lj = (res.x).reshape(4,N)[1]
ai = (res.x).reshape(4,N)[2]
bi = (res.x).reshape(4,N)[3]
```

Which is essentially the same just changing the minimization technique. From `np.sum(Bj)` and `np.sum(Lj)` is easy to see that the results are in agreement with the constraints imposed, which were not working previously.

Answer (score 1):

Not a complete answer, just some hints in arbitrary order:

- Your initial point `x0` is **not** feasible because it contradicts both of your constraints. This can easily be observed by evaluating your constraints at `x0`. Under the hood, Ipopt typically detects this and tries to find a feasible initial point. However, it's highly recommended to provide a feasible initial point whenever possible.
- Your variable bounds are not well-defined. Evaluating your objective at your bounds yields multiple divisions by zero. For example, the denominator `np.tan(b[i])` is zero if and only if b[i] = 0, so 0 isn't a valid value for all of your `b[i]`s. Proceeding similarly for the other terms, you should obtain `0 < b[i] < pi/2` and `0 ≤ a[i] < pi/2`. Here, you can model the strict inequalities by `0 + eps ≤ b[i] ≤ pi/2 - eps` and `0 ≤ a[i] ≤ pi/2 - eps`, where `eps` is a sufficiently small positive number.
- If you really want to impose that the objective function is always positive, you can simply add the inequality constraint Fnret(x) >= 0, i.e. `{'type': 'ineq', 'fun': Fnret}`.

In Code:

```py
# bounds
eps = 1e-8
bounds = [(0, None)]*2*N + [(0, np.pi/2 - eps)]*N + [(0+eps, np.pi/2 - eps)]*N

# (feasible) initial guess
x0 = eps*np.ones(4*N)
x0[[0, N]] = [Bi-(N-1)*eps, Li-(N-1)*eps]

# constraints
cons = [{'type': 'eq', 'fun': Brhs},
        {'type': 'eq', 'fun': Lrhs},
        {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': Fnret}]

res = minimize_ipopt(Fnret, x0, constraints=cons, bounds=bounds, options={'disp': 5})
```

Last but not least, this still doesn't converge to a stationary point, so chances are that there's indeed no local minimum. From here, you can try experimenting with other (feasible!) initial points and double-check the math of your problem. It's also worth providing the exact gradient and constraint Jacobians.

Comment: Thank you for your hint @joni, It'll help me in future programming as well. One thing that is weird for me is that changing the order of the constraints inside `cons` also affects the final result.

Comment: I've just changed the minimization method adopting `scipy.optmize.minime` with the `trust-constr` method and it worked just fine. Tank you for your insights @joni.

Comment: @MateusForcelini Can you please post your fully working code snippet as an answer (and accept it)? I have great doubts that the trust-constr method finds a stationary point while Ipopt does not, so I'm really curious to see it.